# Обособление запятыми вставочной конструкции

Tags: запятые

Как правильно? Я думаю, вариант 1 правильный, так как нужно обособить и *там недостающие*, и оборот с союзом *чтобы*, который после тире второго таки заканчивается.

1. Вам стоит знать, что если просится, **чтобы Вы написали какие-то слова сами, – так как там надо, например, расставить буквы, там недостающие, – то** Вам надо первое таки слово обязательно написать с большой таки буквы, а после последнего слова – поставить точку.
2. Вам стоит знать, что если просится, **чтобы Вы написали какие-то слова сами – так как там надо, например, расставить буквы, там недостающие, – то** Вам надо первое таки слово обязательно написать с большой таки буквы, а после последнего слова – поставить точку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я бы написала так** (два тире, две запятые, частицу ТО лучше убрать):

*Вам стоит знать, что если просится, чтобы Вы написали какие-то слова сами, – **так как там надо, например, расставить буквы, там недостающие,** – Вам надо первое таки слово обязательно написать с большой таки буквы, а после последнего слова – поставить точку.*

**По [Розенталю, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123):**

Первая запятая закрывает **придаточное** (союз ЧТОБЫ), вторая запятая ставится и по **основной конструкции**, и по **обособленному** обороту. Если бы оборота не было, то вторая запятая все равно бы ставилась.

Comment: Надо, если убирать *то*, поставленное мною небезосновательно-таки, ставить ещё и запятую после *что*, т. к., если мы так-таки пишем, нет второй части союза (из-за чего запятая и пропадает).

Comment: Да, вы правы, но тире перед ТО плохо смотрится. Может, лучше поставить запятую после  ЧТО?

Comment: Мне и то и то по-хорошему звучит. Как писать такие предложения – выбор каждого.

Comment: Да, выбор каждого. Просто я а текстах редко вижу сочетание этих знаков.

Comment: Можете-таки сказать, нужна ли здесь-таки запятушоночка? *Я много ягод ем **(,)** – бруснику, чернику, арбузы, например, – так как, по-моему, они и вкусные, и очень, помимо этого, полезные таки.* (Я думаю, запятую надо ставить, так как слово *например* ставит запятую в конце вставной конструкции, а надо ещё-с же то обособить и идущее впереди придаточное, с союза *что* начинающееся-таки.

Comment: Не совсем поняла: а где придаточное (ЧТО)? И еще есть сомнения по поводу "например" .  Оно относится ко всему ряду?  Обычно оно стоит перед рядом после обобщающего слова.

Comment: Я перепутал – я имел в виду придаточное с *так как*. Я специально поставил *например* в конец, и, по-моему, предложение звучит нормальненько.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148584/discussion-between---and-sharon).

Comment: Я много ягод ем, – бруснику, чернику, арбузы, например, – так как, по-моему, они и вкусные, и очень, помимо этого, полезные таки.  Весь ряд уточняющий, так как есть "например". И добавляем два тире для обозначения присоединения. Нестандартная задача.

Comment: Хорошо, но, может, вы согласитесь с моим последним ответом?

Comment: Я думаю, что не надо запятую перед *ем* ставить, так как после *например* запятая стоит и для этого самого *например*, и для обособления придаточного с *так как*.

Comment: Да, все верно..  Без первой запятой предложение сразу смотрится некорректно (даже без анализа).